# C# why two same thread fire same method at same time?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety, nfc

First of all my question is quite complicated (for me) and I try to explain.

I have a WPF application which is working with NFC tags. Couple days ago this code was worked properly but now somethings messed up.
First I have a method which is reading data from NFC tag like this:

```
    private void NFCCard_OnCardInserted()
    {

        CheckCard();

    }

    private bool CheckCard()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_object)
            {
                NFCCard.Connect(CardReader, SHARE.Shared, PROTOCOL.T0orT1);
                APDUPlayer player = new APDUPlayer(ApduListFile, NFCCard);
                if (nfcFunction.NFCLogin(player))
                {
                    string TempCompanyID = "";

                    //--Read data
                }
                DateTime cartOpenedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(OpenedDate);

                if (CartNo == "" || CompanyID.ToString() == "" || Convert.ToInt32(limit) <= 0 || isactive == "False" || cartOpenedDate.ToShortDateString() != DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() || CartType == "Staff")
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
                    {
                        ShowCardNo(txtCardNo, "Geçersiz Kart!");
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    //-- Some internal code

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            StationSession.WriteLog("write log bla bla", exc);
        }
    }
```

Now is the funny thing when I check the threads windows of VS two same thread try to run NFCCard_OnCardInserted() method at same time.

[image: Threads window]
For this reason I put lock state but the problem is this method firing two times. And its make big trouble for me because the card transaction time is being double right now (almost 3 second for some transaction. I cannot explain to people you will wait with cart at cart reader like this :/ ). By the way I check whole page for this method reference, just this code should use this method.

```
NFCCard.OnCardInserted += new CardInsertedEventHandler(NFCCard_OnCardInserted);
```

So how can I fix this problem without workaround. Because I have several page and method which is using NFC cart thread. I need to find clear way for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Verify (with the debugger, at the latest moment) that there is only 1 handler for OnCardInserted.

Comment: where this was initialized    NFCCard.OnCardInserted += new CardInsertedEventHandler(NFCCard_OnCardInserted);

Comment: Okey I will try that in a second but I just forget this info. At every line when I am debuging without lock state VS warning like this "The process or thread has changed since last step" and VS is being crazy. Like debug line 123 then jump to start of method like 110.

Comment: I am using this framework for NFC transaction [NFC Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET).
And implementation is like this.

`private void SelectICard()
        {
            
                if (NFCCard != null)
                    NFCCard.Disconnect(DISCONNECT.Unpower);

                NFCCard = new CardNative();
                NFCCard.OnCardInserted += new CardInsertedEventHandler(NFCCard_OnCardInserted);
                NFCCard.OnCardRemoved += new CardRemovedEventHandler(NFCCard_OnCardRemoved);


            
        }`

Comment: @HenkHolterman I debug it and yes very end of this method just one handler for OnCardInserted.The other thread was gone.

Comment: for thid `The process or thread has changed since last step` you are executing too many threads at the same time so  check if your device need a kind of  Ack to  interrupt invoking  the  method

Comment: It's still not clear. Which method is 'this method' ? You should check in `CheckCard()`. Also not clear: How often do you call `SelectICard()` ?

Comment: Basically this cart framework is using thread at background for detecting tag.But I checked this thread before and my threads were working well together at peace.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am calling SelectICard() at ctor of my page. So one time for this page. And CheckCard method is calling at NFCCardInserted event.

Comment: Place breakpoint on `if (NFCCard != null)` if you hitting breakpoint twice I think problem is that you not unsubscribing to previous event handlers. Try to change code to this: `if (NFCCard != null) { NFCCard.OnCardInserted -= NFCCard_OnCardInserted; NFCCard.OnCardRemoved -= NFCCard_OnCardRemoved; NFCCard.Disconnect(DISCONNECT.Unpower); }NFCCard = new CardNative();.... `

Comment: Is the `NFCCard` a component on you form/window? Could it be that you already bound the `OnCardInserted` event there?